# AlarmManagerIntent doesn't get called

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I want to use the AlarmManager to call a BroadcastReciever:

```
Context ctx=getApplicationContext();
Intent StartIntent = new Intent(ctx, tartReceiver.class);

AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC, StartTime.toMillis(false), PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 6,
                        StartIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT ));
```

The receiver is declared in the manifest like this:

```
<receiver android:process=":remote" android:name=".StartReceiver" android:exported="true"/>
```

But nothing ever happens. If I use ctx.sendBroadcast(StartIntent), the intend gets called, so it should be all right, or not?
I also checked the StartTime, it should be ok and I tried also 0 (which should cause the Intent to be called immediately according to the documentation).

What must I change to get it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JonathanK,

You want `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` not `PendingIntent.getActivity()`.